# SwiftMailer crashes sending message

Tags: php, silex

I'm trying to send an email through SwiftMailer but it crashes without any error.
I've searched around, found a lot of guys with same problem but, any of the solutions I've found helped me.

I have this code:

```
        $transporter = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('webmail.xxx.xxx', 25)
            ->setUsername("XXXXXXX")
            ->setPassword("XXXXXX");

        $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transporter);

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance('SUBJECT')
            ->setFrom(array('noreply@yoursite.com'))
            ->setTo(array('user@yoursite.com'))
            ->setBody('This is ma message man');

        $result = $mailer->send($message);
        echo "bla bla bla";
```

It doesn't reach the echo/error_log part.

What am I missing?
Also I'm using silex

Update:

Initially I tried the configurations on silex page:

http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/swiftmailer.html

configuring the swiftmailer options in index.php and sending the email in the controller but I got the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host localhost [Connection refused #111]
```

So I tried the other approach...

Comment: go into php.ini, turn on display_errors and error_reporting, then try again.

Comment: It's on and still no errors :(